# Tab completion for pdf files with spaces in path

Tags: command-line, pdf, auto-completion

I want to open the pdf file `~/dir1\ with\ spaces/dir2/file.pdf` from the command line. I type `evince ~/dir1\ with\ spaces/` and hit TAB twice for autocomplete. But I won't get offered `dir2`. After adding more letters like `evince ~/dir1\ with\ spaces/di` to make the completion to `dir2` unique, nothing happens at all after hitting TAB (twice). Only after spelling out the complete directory as `evince ~/dir1\ with\ spaces/dir2` and then hitting TAB, autocomplete resumes to work.

Same problem with `okular` instead of `evince`. However using `ls` instead, everything works as expected. The problem seems to be related to the spaces in `dir1\ with\ spaces`, because renaming it to something without a space like `dir1` makes the problem disappear. Also, adding a space to `dir2` is not a problem.

So my impression is: When there is a pdf file within a directory which has a space in its name, autocomplete doesn't consider that directory as a valid completion.

How can I fix this?

I'm on Xubuntu 20.04 in xfce4-terminal. IIRC, on 18.04 things have been working without problem.

Comment: Same for me on stock Ubuntu 20.10. You are right, must be some bug in autocompletion.

Comment: @vanadium thank you for checking. so it's not a specific problem of Xubuntu or xfce4-terminal